# MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT on SQL Server 2014 CTP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to edit this option with the following script:

```
ALTER DATABASE RIServer
SET MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT ON;
GO
```

As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct (per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)). However, I get the following:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT'.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this setting not available on CTP1? Do I need to install CTP2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that option was added between CTP1 and CTP2.

YOU SHOULD NO LONGER BE USING CTP1. Yes, you need to install CTP2.